# PowerShell Read file Modified Date and check if it was modified in the last X hours

Tags: powershell

Using Powershell, How can I read a modified date of a certain file and check it it was modified in the last 24 hours?

This is was I got so far:

```
$temp = Get-Item D:\somefile.txt | select LastWriteTime
```

***EDIT***
Also, I need an example of how to show it was changed in the last 5 seconds

Answer (score 6, accepted):

a one liner :

```
if ( ((Get-Date) - (ls d:\somefile).LastWriteTime).Day -lt 1) {Write-Output "recently modified"}
```

to you second question :

```
$diff=((ls d:\somefile).LastWriteTime - (Get-Date)).TotalSeconds
 if ($diff -gt -5) {Write-Output "recent"}
```

Comment: Are you sure it is working, I have changed it from days to seconds, just to check when it does not echo, and it always echo me that it was recently changed

Comment: yes, but here we are selecting days try this to show full difference : `(get-date) - (ls d:\somefile).LastWriteTime`

Comment: I want to check if it was changed in the last 5 second, it always says "recently changed" even when I did not change it in the last 5 seconds, can you edit you answer for 5 second? Thanks!

Comment: you can use the totalseconds property

Answer (score 2):

I had gone through a similar requirement recently, where I wanted to check the existence of an XML file and to check whether it is modified in the last one hour. Here is the script to do that.

```
$files = Get-ChildItem C:\XmlFolder -Filter *.xml
$timeNow = Get-Date -Format HH
foreach($file in $files)
{
    if ( $file.LastWriteTime.ToString('HH') -eq $timeNow)
    {
        $file.Name
    }
}
```

Now run the command.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In Kayasax's answer, Days should be Day.

```
if ( ((get-date) - (ls d:\somefile).LastWriteTime).day -lt 1){echo "recently modified"}
```

Comment: Thank you, how can I compare if it was changed in the last 5 seconds, and in the last 5 minutes and hours?